# What does following construct mean in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am going thru firebase tutorial / codelabs

I came across a construct like following;

```
// Returns true if a user is signed-in.
function isUserSignedIn() {
  return !!firebase.auth().currentUser;
}
```

in that code what does !! mean ?
does 2 ! cancels each other. If it does cancel why'd have author done !! ?

Comment: Consider that `currentUser` is not a boolean.

Comment: can you please elaborate ? does it mean that !user may or may not be Boolean and 2nd ! guarantees that it is Boolean ?

Comment: They don't always cancel out each other - they also make a type conversion. Sure, `!user` and `!!user` are always boolean, but `user` need not be.

Comment: `!!` is called double negate operator, which in this case makes a boolean type coercion, which means that it turns any value into a boolean. In order to do that, makes a truthy/falsy conversion first. Check this for full explanation: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905159/ch04.html#explicitly----boolean

Comment: Thanks All ; this helps

Comment: https://medium.com/@edplatomail/js-double-bang-or-the-not-operator-part-40e55d089bf0 ???

Comment: Does this means that !! is a coding style and not part of syntax and in theory I can do any numbers of ! -- like !!!!!!thisthing.tatthing